# How to add a countdown timer of 3...2...1...GO in Android?

Tags: android, audio, stopwatch, countdowntimer

I am currently developing a stopwatch but I dont understand how can I add a countdown timer to it which has animations..
It should be triggered at the click of Start Button of the stopwatch and at the same time I have a mp3 sound clip of 3...2...1...Go which should be played with the countdown.. And after that the stopwatch should be triggered...

Sorry for placing so much demands but please give your answers in detail as in which file to put which command...

P.S :- I am using ADT Eclipse provided by Google Inc.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html. Check the developer site

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
long minute = 1000*60;//convert millescond to minute 
long close_minutes = 5*minute;//set for 5 minutes

         Handler handler = new Handler();
         Runnable r=new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  //do something count down is finished
             }
         };
        handler.postDelayed(r, close_minutes);
```

Comment: my friend did  you have layout source code ? if so post it here then we can help u